# gitlab-ce: change clone url without using external_url in gitlab.rb

Tags: docker, docker-compose, gitlab

I have set up a default install of `gitlab-ce` with `docker-compose`

```
services:
  gitlab:
    image: gitlab/gitlab-ce:latest
    restart: always
    container_name: gitlab
    ports:
      - 127.0.0.0:80:80
      - 127.0.0.0:443:443
      - 127.0.0.0:22:22
    volumes:
      - gitlab-config:/etc/gitlab:z
      - gitlab-logs:/var/log/gitlab:z
      - gitlab-data:/var/opt/gitlab:z
```

My issue is, that the generated `"Clone with Http"` url of every project contains an incorrect path.

[Example "Clone with HTTP"-URL](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pA1sC.png)

###### I dont know how i can change this without using the parameter `external_url` in `etc\gitlab\gitlab.rb`?

The problem with this approach is that it also activates the built in `nginx` component of gitlab, which i do not want since I am using my own nginx server as a reverse proxy for 2 `gitlab` instances.

It all works if I manually change the url before copying, but there must be a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

You must use the `external_url` parameter for this value in the UI to be correct.

> The problem with this approach is that it also activates the built in nginx component of gitlab

You can explicitly disable this in the `gitlab.rb`:

```rb
nginx['enable'] = false
```

It is also possible to change the SSH address independently of the HTTPS address using `gitlab_rails['gitlab_ssh_host']` setting in the `gitlab.rb`.

For more information on available settings, see the [`gitlab.rb` template](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/omnibus-gitlab/blob/master/files/gitlab-config-template/gitlab.rb.template).